# Getting ODBC 3700 error when ruby on rails is trying to add_index to new table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sql-server-2005

I am using the gem `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter` to connect to an existing Microsoft SQL Server using Ruby on Rails. I modified the `config\application.rb` file to set my `table_name_prefix` as the following

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = 'msr.FSCR_'
```

So that all of my tables created with Ruby on Rails are in the `msr` schema and are grouped together with the `FSCR_` prefix. I have a table / scaffold that was created using the following

```
rails generate scaffold Customer name:string status:string 
rake db:migrate
```

which created the table `msr.FSCR_customers` which is correct. Then I created a model for sites as follows

```
rails generate scaffold Site name:string addr1:string addr2:string city:string
    state:string zip:string
```

and the model/scaffold was generated correctly. The generate command created the database migration file `20120718221629_create_sites.rb` as follows

```
class CreateSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sites do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :addr1
      t.string :addr2
      t.string :addr3
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.string :phone
      t.string :fax
      t.integer :created_by
      t.references :customer

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sites, :customer_id
  end
end
```

However when I run the `rake db:migrate` commend I get the following error message:

```
ODBC::Error: 37000 (102) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect
syntax near '.'.: CREATE INDEX [index_msr].[FSCR_sites_on_customer_id] ON [msr].
[FSCR_sites] ([customer_id])
```

If I comment out the line `add_index :sites, :customer_id` It creates the table just fine. When the table is created, I see that my foreign key is not there. How do I change / fix this issue?

**UPDATE**

I think I found the problem but I don't know how to change it. Because I'm using a table prefix of `msr.FSCR_` it is trying to create the index name with the prefix of `index_` + `msr.FSCR_` + {index_name} so the insert is trying to create

```
[index_msr].[sites_on_customer_id]
```

There is no schema of `index_msr` so I would expect this to fail. What I really want is the index name to be is

```
[index_msr_sites_on_customer_id]
```

Is there a way to remove the `].[` from the create index section of the `ActiveRecord` class?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a customer_id column.. Would it help to add that? Or just add the index on sites and get rid of the customer_id

Comment: with the line `customer:references` you get the customer_id column created in the database on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by modifying the db migration file generated from rails as follows:

**GENERATED FILE**

```
class CreateSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sites do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :addr1
      t.string :addr2
      t.string :addr3
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.string :phone
      t.string :fax
      t.integer :created_by
      t.references :customer

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sites, :customer_id
  end
end
```

**UPDATED FILE**

```
class CreateSites < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :sites do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :addr1
      t.string :addr2
      t.string :addr3
      t.string :city
      t.string :state
      t.string :zip
      t.string :phone
      t.string :fax
      t.integer :created_by
      t.references :customer

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :sites, :customer_id, :name => 'sites_by_customer'
  end
end
```